# How can I play a Psychic Necromancer using Occult Adventures material?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, necromancy, occult-magic, psychic-class

I'd like to play a Psychic Necromancer using *Occult Adventures* material in *Pathfinder*.

There is the Haunted discipline; however, that's not what I'm looking for. I was hoping more along the line of a traditional Necromancer that uses psychic energy to reanimate corpses and cast necromancy spells.

I am open to any source, or even homebrew, although in that case I'd like a link to where it might of been posted somewhere.  I know it'd be an easy thing to make for myself, by Frankensteining a sorcerer with the undead bloodline, and a necromantic archetype, but I'd like something more Psychic-unique.

Comment: To clarify, you want to use the Psychic class or simply use psychic magic?

Comment: Yes, The Occult Psychic, from Pathfinder.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

#### Occultist

The [occultist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/occultist) is generally considered one of the more balanced Pathfinder classes, and has quite a few good options. If you focus on the necromancy implement, you'll have access to a small wealth of abilities, including skeleton-summoning, creation of zombified temporary familiars, negative energy manipulation, and more. Just *having* a necromancy implement also enhances your undead creation.

The class also comes with self-buffs and buffs you can place on others, depending on what other schools you pick. Finally, it gets *lesser animate dead* as a 2nd-level spell and *animate dead* as a 3rd-level spell. Overall, I believe that the occultist would be a better psychic necromancer than the psychic base class.

Comment: This is the way I will most likely have to go. I just was hoping for a Psychic.   It seems every class in Pathfinder has a necro archetype, but this one. Not even 3rd party.

Answer (score 2):

### Psychic Sorcerer Bloodline

If you desire to play a psychic spellcaster without actually playing the [Psychic class](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/psychic/), you can try the [Psychic sorcerer bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/psychic-sorcerer-bloodline/). With this, you gain [psychic spellcasting](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/psychic-magic/), you gain a few psychic-themed bloodline abilities and spells, and can freely pick your spells from the wizard/sorcerer list.

I will suggest you go this route if you want something closer to the Necromancer wizard spell school, as there are very few undead-themed spells on the [Psychic spell list](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/psychic/).

### Spiritualist class

The [Spiritualist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/spiritualist/) has several archetypes that are thematically fitting for a necromancer spellcaster, especially so when you consider they have a *ghost* as a pet (their [Phantom](http://pathfinderwiki.com/mediawiki/images/thumb/b/b2/Estra.jpg/250px-Estra.jpg)). To name a few archetypes:

- [Necrologist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/spiritualist/archetypes/paizo-llc-spiritualist-archetypes/necrologist-spiritualist-archetype/): *The vile spiritualists known as necrologists reach farther toward the Negative Energy Plane, however, and for whatever evil purpose, they bring back malevolent spirits whose passions have turned to vengeance and hate for all life.*
- [Geist Chaneller](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/spiritualist/archetypes/paizo-llc-spiritualist-archetypes/geist-channeler-spiritualist-archetype/): *Incapable of manifesting in ectoplasmic form and devoid of human emotions, these strange entities are much closer to ghosts than most other phantoms.*
- [Usher of Lost Souls](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/spiritualist/archetypes/paizo-llc-spiritualist-archetypes/usher-of-lost-souls-spiritualist-archetype/): *Ushers of lost souls are spiritualists who focus on bringing the souls of the dead to their final judgments at the end of the River of Souls. To this end, they specialize in destroying undead and in laying haunts to rest.*

The [spiritualist spell list](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/spell-lists-and-domains/spiritualist) also contains several necromancy spells related to undeads, like [Animate Dead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/animate-dead), [Boneshaker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/boneshaker), [Undead Anatomy](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/u/undead-anatomy-i) and [Create Undead](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/create-undead/). Those spells are all missing from the Psychic spell list.

### Haunted Psychic Discipline

The [Haunted](http://archivesofnethys.com/PsychicDisciplinesDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Haunted) discipline (from [Haunted Heroes Handbook player companion](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9nft?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Haunted-Heroes-Handbook)) should be thematically fitting for a necromancer-type psychic character. You gain more powers related to handling spirits and haunts than raising undead though.

> Your powers interact with the spiritual world, attracting the attention of minor spirits and undead.

If you plan on using psychic spells against undead, I will suggest you take the [Will of the Dead](http://archivesofnethys.com/PhrenicAmplificationsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Will%20of%20the%20Dead) phrenic amplification, so they can be affected by mind-affecting spells instead of being immune, and thus, you can play some sort of *enchanter of the dead* type of character.

This is the only published discipline/archetype that is even close to a necromancer for the Psychic class. Discarding this option will lead you to **other classes** that will use psychic magic and have different mechanics and spell lists.

To be honest, personally, I wouldn't even consider the Psychic class, as they are thematically tied to mind, telekinesis and astral themes, not undead and necromancy. To become a proper necromancer, an archetype or discipline would first have to address the spell list and add more undead-themed spells ot the class. This option is here simply to address the class.

Another option is **adding necromancy spells to the Psychic spell list**, by making a [samsaran](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-samsaran/) character and (hand) pick a few necromancy spells with the Mystic Past Life racial trait, and with this, you could pick spells from the *Spiritualist* spell list and add to the Psychic spell list:

> **Mystic Past Life** (Su) You can **add spells from another spellcasting class to the spell list of your current spellcasting class**. You add a number of spells equal to 1 + your spellcasting class’s key ability score bonus (Wisdom for clerics, and so on). The spells must be the same type (arcane or divine) as the spellcasting class you’re adding them to. For example, you could add divine power to your druid class spell list, but not to your wizard class spell list because divine power is a divine spell.

Comment: "There is the Haunted discipline, however, that's not what I'm looking for," says the question, yet that's the first thing suggested? Is this an attempt to challenge the frame?

Comment: @HeyICanChan i was going to answer only with the sorcerer bloodline, but after a second reading of the Haunted, i thought it was worth to list it so later i could mention that the psychic has very few undead-themed spells.

Comment: Like I commented above, about Occultist. I'd really wanted a Psychic.  I've been searching and nothing seems to be written.  I'd thought of  making one myself and still might.  (Limited reanimate body powers, possession and life draining spells). Mostly for now I think I can settle for a different creepy minion archetype. The Doll Mage. http://hastur.net/wiki/Doll_Mage_(Apath)   3rd party. That's fine with me. They also have a Dead discipline at Apath, but I think I will go your way with Haunted after all.  Thanks for all The work you put into this answer.

Comment: @Roland added a note about samsarans, if that helps.